# How to make a central VBA code for multiple Excel files

Tags: excel, vba

**the situation**

I have made a project planner in Excel, each project has its own Excel workbook which is based on a template file. So when a new project is made, the excel files gets copied and used as a planner.

**The problem**

Sometimes there will be updates for the template file such as bugfixes and new functions. When the VBA code in the template file is updated, only the project after the update has the newest VBA code. So exciting files don't have the updated VBA code and need to be updated manually (copy and paste the code in the existing file).

**What I want**

I want the Excel workbooks to be backwards compatible. So when I update the main template, the VBA code in the existing files need to get updated as well.

**What I tried/found**

On the web, I found two options to do this. The first is called an Add-in. I don't know yet how to make such add-in or set up one. Are there any good tutorials on how they work and how to make one? And are Addins slowing down excel?

The second option is a main file with the code. So when I run the macro the central file gets opened and the project planner use the function: application.run to get the code to run. I did some testing with this and I found that this really slows excel down a lot.

**The question**

Are there any other and better options?
If not:
Is there a good tutorial on how to make a good add-in? and slows add-ins Excel down?

Comment: Using an "add-in" for your code does not slow it down at all. It's just an XLAM file that is loaded into memory each time you open any spreadsheet. They are easy to make.. you just make your XLSM like normal, and then save it as an XLAM, then load it as an add-in. There are plenty of tutorials about how to do this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584990/xlam-addin-how-to-create-update-process

Comment: If you want to have "just the code" separate from the Excel workbook, you can export modules by right clicking on them in the VB editor. This applies to code, class, and form modules. Other than that, it's not clear to me what you want

Comment: edited my question to make it more clear, I hope.